# API (.NET 6) can't connect with SQL Server database after updates anymore

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker, api

I am a student software engineering and i am having trouble fixing this issue for the last few days and i can't seem to solve it. I already read a lot about this error but i did not manage to solve this.

I am using a .NET 6 API with Entity framework and for my database i have a mssql server database (2019). I am running the database inside a docker container.

At first the connection was working fine but after some updates from the nuget package manager the connection broke and I got this error in the console when executing API Calls:

> Error Number:53,State:0,Class:20 A network-related or
> instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
> SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
> that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
> allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
> Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

It is weird because when I open Microsoft SQL Server Management studio, i can see the database tables that i have created with the same credentials as login. I also can read and modify the data inside of the tables.

[image: Screenshot of the Database running inside the docker container with Object Explorer]

I can provide more information if needed.

**Update:**

Some more information about the connection:

Connection string:

> Server=host.docker.internal;database=Contentdb;User
> Id=sa;Password=Pasword;

How i have setup my database with Docker:

> docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Password"
> --name contentdb -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

Comment: For agent, you can't start that; SQL Server Express does not suggest SQL Server Agent.

Comment: *"I am running the database inside a docker container."* That image is of a windows installation of SQL Server, *not* a Docker installed instance. If you have installed the Docker Image of SQL Server, you need to first check that Container is running. Can you see the container running if you put `docker container list` into your command line interface, or can you see the Container is running Docker Desktop?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have updated the post. I can see the container running and there are no errors when i investigate it on Docker Desktop. The image works because i can connect to the database with SQL Server management studio (I added a screenshot of this)

Comment: I'm talking about [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phHXP.png). That image **cannot** be for your docker container. Perhaps that's the problem though. Try stopping that instance and the SQL Browser.

Comment: No that is right. I added this picture to show the SQL Server environment on my pc. I thought there were some related services that could be why i am not able to connect to my database anymore. Maybe i needed to have a service running like the Agent.

Comment: Again, [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phHXP.png) *cannot* be for your Docker Instance. Dockerised/Linux based installations of SQL Server **cannot** be named instances and that [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phHXP.png) *clearly* demonstrates a instance named `SQLE...` (presumably `SQLEXPRESS`). The SQL Server Configuration manager is also *specifically* built for Windows hosted instances. So, again, that [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phHXP.png) showing your "docker container is running", is *not* doing that at all. Again, try turning those services off and see what happens.

Comment: Hmm okay. I though that the services that i showed in that screenshot could help understand why the connection could not work. The docker image is running and i could also post a screenshot of it in the post. I added a screenshot of the database that is running inside the container at the top of the post. I tried stopping the Browser service but there was no difference in the error. Maybe the issue is no inside the SQL Server Configuration manager. I solved the issues in the past regarding SQL Server related problems with this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249486/discussion-between-luca-and-larnu).

Comment: Images won't help *at all*. If SQL Server runs inside a container, you need to explicitly map host (ie your machine) ports to a container port. You do that in the `docker run -p host_port:cont_port` command. You need to modify your connection string to match that port too. Post the ports you mapped and the connection string *as text*

Comment: If you use Docker Desktop you can check the ports used by a running container in the container's `Inspect` tab.

Comment: I updated the post with the connectionstring and docker information. I know that the database is working but i can't figure out why my api suddenly can't connect with the database anymore. The database has to be online and available to access it with MSSMS. The port of the database container is also shown in my screenshot that shows the object explorer

Comment: The connection string is wrong. Since you map `1433` to the *host*'s 1433 the `Server` should be `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`, ie `Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=Contentdb;User Id=sa;Password=Pasword;`. If you map to a different port it should be added after the host name `Server=localhost,5678;...`

Comment: `host.docker.internal` is used to allow application inside the container to talk to the host. If you're trying to connect to the database server on the host, then a) this is unusual b) you should include the instance name, ie `host.docker.internal\SQLExpress`. Named instances don't run on 1433.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249488/discussion-between-luca-and-panagiotis-kanavos).